# Skjor should stay dead during the Companions quest right?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I returned to Vilkas after completing a quest, I look around and Skjor is sitting next to Aela. I have completed the Companions quest. Any possible answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Skjor should stay dead after finishing the Companions quest, [The Silver Hand](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Silver_Hand). However, according to the [UESP wiki, there are bugs associated with Skjor](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skjor):

> #### Bugs
>
> - Sometimes Skjor will reappear in Jorrvaskr, alive or dead, after he
>   dies during the events of The Silver Hand. He may also reappear in
>   Jorrvaskr and still give out quests. You will not get a bounty for
>   killing him if he is alive.
> - Sometimes Skjor can be found wandering Skyrim while half-buried in the
>   ground after finishing the quest The Silver Hand.

The same UESP wiki article also states that both bugs are fixed by the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch.](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Unofficial_Skyrim_Patch)